# How to know the calling activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity which is called by a few other activities. For example, I have Activity1, Activity2, and Activity3.
Activity1 calls Activity2 and passes a parameter.
Activity3 also calls Activity2 and passes a parameter.

Now, based on the calling activity, Activity2 performs some task.
How do I know which activity is calling Activity2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know if an activity is called using startActivityForResult or simply called by using startActivity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564461/how-to-know-if-an-activity-is-called-using-startactivityforresult-or-simply-call)

Comment: do you mean it?? how can a question be a duplicate of another which has been asked few months later ??

Comment: First of all don't be panic about duplication. I am not pointing any thing bad from your side. I don't thing that duplication depends on the date of question has been asked. See a thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812003/difference-between-oncreate-and-onstart/6812066 where I answered, question was asked many month before target question.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**A. If you can use startActivityForResult**

As per [Zain Ali's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12194077/340235) below: If you can start Activity with startActivityForResult()  then you can get name of calling Activity class by this.getCallingActivity().getClassName();

**B. If you can not use startActivityForResult**

If you can not use startActivityForResult(), then you can use following method: 
You can pass additional parameter in intent, check the value in activity and act accordingly.

1)  Define an interface or constants class to define integer constants to indicate calling activity

```
public interface ActivityConstants {
            public static final int ACTIVITY_1 = 1001;
            public static final int ACTIVITY_2 = 1002;
            public static final int ACTIVITY_3 = 1003;
}
```

2)  Add extra parameter in intent while calling Activity2.

```
        Intent act2 = new Intent(context, Activity2.class);
                act2.putExtra("calling-activity", ActivityConstants.ACTIVITY_1);
    // or ActivityConstants.ACTIVITY_3 if called form Activity3
startActivity(act2);
```

3)  Check the value of this extra parameter in Activity2 and act accordingly..

```
int callingActivity = getIntent().getIntExtra("calling-activity", 0);

        switch (callingActivity) {
        case ActivityConstants.ACTIVITY_1:
            // Activity2 is started from Activity1
            break;
        case ActivityConstants.ACTIVITY_3:
            // Activity2 is started from Activity3
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 64):

If you start the activity with `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)`, then you can get calling activity by `getCallingActivity().getClassName()`.

Comment: so how to actually get the activity callers actual instance ?

Comment: @ralphgabb just remove .getClassName() part

Answer (score 9):

In your calling activity (FirstActivity):

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("classFrom", FirstActivity.class.toString());
startActivity(i);
```

And add the following code in the onCreate of the called activity (SecondActivity):

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

if (bundle.getString("classFrom").equals(FirstActivity.class.toString())) {
     //Do some task
}
```

Notice that you should be carefully because the bundle object can't be null when you perform "b.getString("classFrom")".

Answer (score 2):

You could pass an additional parameter that specifies the calling `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully use: (Activity).getLocalClassName()

Answer (score 0):

Pass anything(String/ int etc.) to putExtra and base on that do the your work like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra("PARENT_ACTIVITY_REF", "ParentActivityIsA");
     startActivity(intent);
```

And then receive in child like

```
String parentActivityRef = intent.getStringExtra("PARENT_ACTIVITY_REF");
```

then

```
if (parentActivityRef.equals("ParentActivityIsA"){
              // do your work here
}else if ...{
             // ...
}else{
     //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm Using This line

```
    if (((((ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).getRunningTasks(1).get(0).baseActivity)).compareTo(new ComponentName(getPackageName()
                    , AnyActivityWantToCheck.class.getName())) == 0){
// do somthing .....
    }
```

i hope it work with you

Comment: Note: this method is only intended for debugging and presenting task management user interfaces. and is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using companion object as in the following example:

```
class MainActivity: BaseActivity {
    ...
    LoginActivity.callerActivity = this
    it.context.startActivity(Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity::class.java))
    ...
}

class LoginActivity : BaseActivity() {
    companion object {
        var callerActivity: AppCompatActivity? = null
    }

    ...

    callerActivity?.let {
        it.callSomething()
    }
}
```