# Difference between onCreate() and onStart()?

Tags: android, android-activity, oncreate, onstart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Activity Life Cycle - difference between onPause() and OnStop()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-difference-between-onpause-and-onstop)

I was wondering - **what is the difference between `onCreate()` and `onStart()` methods?**

I think that `onStart()` is a redundant method. `onCreate()` will ALWAYS be called (At least in my last two projects).

Can any one explain the difference?

Answer (score 373, accepted):

Take a look at the life cycle of Activity.

<sup>The following image and documentation excerpt are reproduced from work created and [shared by the Android Open Source Project](http://code.google.com/policies.html) and used according to terms described in the [Creative Commons 2.5 Attribution License](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.5/).</sup>

[image]

Where

```
***onCreate()***
```

> Called when the activity is first created. This is where you should do all of your normal static set up: create views, bind data to lists, etc. This method also provides you with a Bundle containing the activity's previously frozen state, if there was one.
> Always followed by onStart().

```
***onStart()***
```

> Called when the activity is becoming visible to the user.
> Followed by onResume() if the activity comes to the foreground, or onStop() if it becomes hidden.

And you can write your simple class to take a look when these methods call. The following code is adapted and simplified from the example and demo application found in [Lifecycle Methods in Details](http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/lifecycleMethods.html), which is a very good article to understand the life cycle.

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private final static String TAG = "TestActivity";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Log.i(TAG, "On Create .....");
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
    * @see android.app.Activity#onDestroy()
    */
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() { 
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG, "On Destroy .....");
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
    * @see android.app.Activity#onPause()
    */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() { 
        super.onPause();
        Log.i(TAG, "On Pause .....");
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
    * @see android.app.Activity#onRestart()
    */
    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Log.i(TAG, "On Restart .....");
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
    * @see android.app.Activity#onResume()
    */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(TAG, "On Resume .....");
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
    * @see android.app.Activity#onStart()
    */
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.i(TAG, "On Start .....");
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
    * @see android.app.Activity#onStop()
    */
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.i(TAG, "On Stop .....");
    }
}
```

Link to android documentation [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for details.

Answer (score 31):

`onCreate()` method gets called when activity gets created, and its called only once in whole Activity life cycle.
where as `onStart()` is called when activity is stopped... I mean it has gone to background and its `onStop()` method is called by the os. `onStart()` may be called multiple times in Activity life cycle.[More details here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html)

Comment: `onCreate()` method gets called when activity created and `onStart()` method called when activity comes from `onPause()` or `onResume()` .

Comment: `onCreate()` , will be called in two scenarios , one when activity is first created, and second when activity goes through configuration changes. It is mandatory to implement `onCreate()` in our activity. `onStart()` can be called multiple times. It is not mandatory to implement `onStart()`.