# How to create, start, resume, pause, stop, destroy android activity during testing

Tags: java, android, testing, android-activity, instrumentation

I wish to capture data from the views in the activity, then pause it, then resume it and ensure that the data has not changed. I tried calling Activity#onPause() in ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2#setUp() but I get an error.

Comment: See codes : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812003/difference-between-oncreate-and-onstart/6812066#6812066

Answer (score 0, accepted):

press back button, press home button, and keep other applications open for some time. most of them you asked for will be called.. and calling those methods explicitly is a wrong move.

Comment: I understand the activity lifecycle. I have an EditText that I want to make sure the content remains the same after the application has been closed then opened again.