# Activity can do without onStart() particularly and onStop() as well?

Tags: android

This is a text I have copied and pasted from [this training tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html).

"Because the system retains your Activity instance in system memory when it is stopped, **it's possible that you don't need to implement the onStop() and onRestart() (or even onStart() methods at all.** For most activities that are relatively simple, the activity will stop and restart just fine and **you might only need to use onPause()** to pause ongoing actions and disconnect from system resources."

I don't understand it. Because to the best of my knowledge, an activity is only stopped by calling onStop() and is only started by calling onStart(). How can an activity start at all without an onStart method.

Do you people understand what they mean in this paragraph?

Comment: an activity is stopped, **and** onStop is called. It is only a feedback thing, calling onSomething does not cause something to happen. Also, you need to read about polymorphism. Just because you don't define onStart in your activity does not mean there is no onStart. In fact, there is the super.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they are confusing you with the word "stop" which appears to have multiple meanings in the paragraph.

I would rephrase it as

> Because the system retains your Activity instance in system memory
>   when it is *not in the foreground*, it's possible that you don't need
>   to implement the onStop() and onRestart() (or even onStart() methods
>   at all. For most activities that are relatively simple, the activity
>   will *suspend* and restart just fine and you might only need to use
>   onPause() to pause ongoing actions and disconnect from system
>   resources.

The point being is that the App can appear to be stopped, when in actual fact, the system has simply paused it and hidden it from the screen. When the user launches it again, the App doesn't need to start (because it technically hasn't stopped), so it is simply resumed.

Comment: "the system has simply paused it and hidden it from the screen." ... but they say that an activity is paused iff it is partially hidden and partially visible; if it is completely hidden, it is in the stopped state.
Thank you for the rephrase though, it has cleared my mind to quite an extent.

Comment: I probably should have used "suspended" instead of "paused" to prevent the same confusion! Sadly, I couldn't think of another synonym meaning "in memory but not executing" - stopped, paused, suspended, argh...

Answer (score 1):

When you make an Activity and extend the base class Activity, there is already code in the **onStop(), onStart(), and onRestart()** methods in the base class.

Your activity simply extends these methods, meaning that you could add more code to them by **Overriding** them.

So, even though Activities are only started and stopped through those methods, you do not have to explicitly override them in your application. In most cases you won't even have to worry about them: They will be called by the base class from which you are extending.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure, An Activity starts from onCreate method , then onStart is called by system. If you override onStart method then your overridden method will be also called after onCreate method. If you don't override , then default version of onStart is called.

onStop is called after onPause.

Please check this link , and take a look at Activity life cycle . Your concept will be clear.
[Difference between onCreate() and onStart()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812003/difference-between-oncreate-and-onstart)

Answer (score 0):

you can use an Activity just fine without - if you need to do something special in onPause() you can override the method:

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();

    // Your magic here!

}
```

Same goes for onStart(), onStop() etc. You don't need to override the methods but you can if you need to do something specific.