# OnResume() Not called in the child activity when used with TabGroupActivity in Xamarin Droid

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, activitygroup

I am using Tabgroupactivity in Xamarin to develop a droid app.
I have a TabGroupActivity with 4 child activities.

**The OnResume() is not being called in any of the child activities.**

Can Anyone please help me with the right solution why is it not being called!! or Is there any fault in my code?

TabGroupActivity.cs

```
namespace RB.Droid
{
[Activity (Label = "TabGroupActivity")]         
public class TabGroupActivity : ActivityGroup
{


    private List<string> _idList;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        if (_idList == null)
            _idList = new List<string> ();



    }


    public void StartChildActivity (string id, Intent intent)
    {
        intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.ClearTop);

        var manager = new LocalActivityManager (this, false);

        var window = MainTabActivity.localActivityManager.StartActivity (id, intent);
        if (window != null) {
            _idList.Add (id);
            SetContentView (window.DecorView);
        }
    }

    public override void FinishActivityFromChild (Activity child, int requestCode)
    {
        var manager = new LocalActivityManager (this, false);
        var index = _idList.Count - 1;

        if (index < 1) {
            Finish ();
            return;
        }

        MainTabActivity.localActivityManager.DestroyActivity (_idList [index], true);
        _idList.RemoveAt (index);
        index--;
        var lastId = _idList [index];
        var lastIntent = MainTabActivity.localActivityManager.GetActivity (lastId).Intent;
        var newWindow = MainTabActivity.localActivityManager.StartActivity (lastId, lastIntent);
        SetContentView (newWindow.DecorView);     
    }

    public override bool OnKeyDown (Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (keyCode == Keycode.Back) {
            return true;
        }
        return base.OnKeyDown (keyCode, e);
    }

    public override bool OnKeyUp (Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (keyCode == Keycode.Back) {
            OnBackPressed ();
            return true;
        }
        return base.OnKeyUp (keyCode, e);
    }

    public override void OnBackPressed ()
    {
        var length = _idList.Count;
        if (length > 1) {
            var manager = new LocalActivityManager (this, false);

            var current = MainTabActivity.localActivityManager.GetActivity (_idList [length - 1]);
            FinishActivityFromChild (current, 0);
        }
    }


}
}
```

SettingsActivityGroup.cs

```
namespace RB.Droid
{

[Activity (Label = "SettingsActivityGroup")]            
public class SettingsActivityGroup : TabGroupActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Create your application here
        StartChildActivity ("Settings", new Intent (this, typeof(Settings)));
    }
}
}
```

Settings.cs

```
namespace RB.Droid
{

[Activity (Label = "Settings")]         
public class Settings : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Create your application here
        TextView tv = new TextView (this);
        tv.Text = "Settings";
        SetContentView (tv);
    }

    protected override void OnResume ()
    {
        base.OnResume ();

        Toast.MakeText (this, "ON RESUME NOT CALLED", ToastLength.Long);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please describe what you are doing, when you want the OnResume Method to be raised (info about the method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume())

Comment: @Joehl: I want to call a method where a user should be checked for his login whenever he comes to the screen. SO i want to call the method in onResume(). It works in android but to my bad, Its not working with xamarin .

Answer (score 0):

Use the `OnStart` Method to do that. We use the this method to load/refresh some ui-data when the view gets displayed.

`OnResume`: The activity goes in Pause state when another activity comes over it. In this case when user pressed back button then `onResume` get's called.

More infos and good explanation to activity lifecycle: [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6812066/2653134)

Comment: yeah, but if you are interchanging between the tabs, OnStart() will not be called. so i need to call  that method even upon shifting between the tabs.