# What is the performance impact of onCreate() and onStart() on activity startup

Tags: android, performance, oncreate, onstart

Whenever a new Activity is created `onCreate` is called. Followed by `onStart`. And `onStart` is called again when activity is back on to the screen. I know this fundamentals. But, what is the actual difference between when you launch the activity.

I mean to say, when you click on some object on current activity, you start a new activity by `startActivity()` method with an intent of new activity. Now `onCreate()` will be called of the second activity and then the `onStart()`. When will be the activity visible to the user? After `onCreate` or after `onStart`? If it is visible after `onCreate` and before `onStart`, and I do some of the operations in `onStart()`, then it will reduce the lag between the user clicking on an object and the screen popping up on screen.

If I move some of the data bindings to onStart will it interfere with the default Activity transitions on lollipop and above (I am not sure about this)?

Is it a good idea to move some of the code to `onStart` to reduce a lag between click and new activity shown on user's screen? If yes, what kind of code can be safely moved to `onStart`? Like data bindings, database queries, etc. ?

Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Comment: Your activity contents will be visible in onResume().

Comment: @Kirtan403 the activity visible to the user on onResume()

Comment: This may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812003/difference-between-oncreate-and-onstart?rq=1

Comment: So it looks like activity visible after onStart and onResume will be called after onStart. So onStart will be called before activity is visible on screen.