# MVP on Android, inject views

Tags: android, performance, architecture, mvp

I follow MVP pattern. I have two methods in the presenter `setView(Avtivity a) & clearView()`

What is better for performance, to call those on `onStart() & onStop()` or `onCreate() & onDestroy`

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean? i use MVP and each View have presenter that have a presenter interface with attachView and detachView

And i always call them on onCreate()

I think you should look at the first answer of this post [Difference between onCreate() and onStart()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812003/difference-between-oncreate-and-onstart)

i think onCreate() is what you should always use if you are attaching a view

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to set Activity View onCreate, and remove it onDestroy, you can also set Fragment View onAttach and remove it onDetach.

I have to add that this is not a concept of performance! You have to avoid memory leak in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

It depends..
There are 3 sets of callbacks you can use

1) `onResume()` `onPause()`
Which will make the view reference available to your presenter only when that view is visible and user can interact with it

2) `onStart()` `onStop()`
Which will make the view reference available to your presenter as above plus if the view is even partially visible

3) `onCreate()` `onDestroy()`
Which will make the view reference available to your presenter as long as it exists basically

- So depends on your use case, do you need to update the view, or do anything if the view is not visible? or intractable?
- Another factor to consider is frequency of calling, because the `onCreate()` `onDestroy()` pair will be called only once for each view, while on the other hand the other ones will be called more frequently