# Android onStart if button clicked

Tags: android, onclicklistener

How do I put an if else statement if a button is clicked on my onStart() to check if button clicked is register or log in?

Here is my code

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.register:
                i = new Intent(this, RegisterCustomer.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.login:
                final String email = memail.getText().toString();
                final String password = mpassword.getText().toString();
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(CustomerLoginActivty.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(CustomerLoginActivty.this, "sign in error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);
    }
```

Comment: what you want to achieve??

Comment: To try and put an if else on my onStart() to check what button is being clicked. is it possible?

Comment: `onStart()` would have already been called. Can you not put `mAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);` in your `onClick()`?

Comment: Refer this i think you are still unclear with LifeCycle https://stackoverflow.com/a/6812066/4762767

Comment: why do you want to check the click in onStart?

Comment: i guess you can not check in onstart as the callbacks will be in onClick of view so it does not matter where you place the logic the response will be in onClick().

Comment: or you can check with a flag if onstart is called on onClick

Comment: If you want to check if button is clicked at once if user stops the app and restarts it, you can also use isClicked =true onRestart() method too. This you can check if button was previously clicked or save flag onsaveinstancestate() and check this onCreate(). It depends on what you wish to achive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a field in class. e.g. int clickedButton;
2. In onStart() check the id using that field.

   ```
   int clickedButton;

   public void onClick(View v) {
       clickedButton = v.getId();
       switch (v.getId()) {
       case R.id.register:
           i = new Intent(this, RegisterCustomer.class);
           startActivity(i);
           finish();
           break;
       case R.id.login:
           final String email = memail.getText().toString();
           final String password = mpassword.getText().toString();
           mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(CustomerLoginActivty.this, new OnCompleteListener < AuthResult > () {@Override
               public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < AuthResult > task) {
                   if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                       Toast.makeText(CustomerLoginActivty.this, "sign in error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
               }
           });
           break;
       }
   }

   @Override
   protected void onStart() {
       super.onStart();
       if(clickedButton != null){
          switch (clickedButton) {
            case R.id.register:
           //do your thing
            case R.id.login:
           //do your thing
          }
       }

       mAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);

   }
   ```