# getView() returns null in second activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-view

I have an app that builds a bundle and passes it to a second activity, for the data within the bundle to be used later.

So far I just want to display one of the elements in the bundle in a `TextView`, to be sure that I can handle the data in activity two. I'm calling `getView().findViewByID(R.id.theTextViewIWant)`, but it is always returning `null`, and the IDE says it cannot resolve `getView()`. I believe it has got to be something I don't fully understand about the `View` that holds the second activity, so I'd appreciate any help.

```
public class MyClass extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mark_student);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();

        Bundle receivedInfo = getIntent().getExtras();
        String unitSelected = receivedInfo.getString("key");

        TextView textViewBox = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textViewBox.setText(unitSelected);
    }
```

I've tried these two other ways of getting the view object, and they haven't worked either:

```
ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) this.findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0); //nope

View fragmentView = getView(); //neither
```

Comment: Hi, is it the bundle that is returning null or your textview? You can text those separately by adding a debug stop point for each of those or even a log and check what gets printed out when the data comes as a bundle and what happens when you try to initialize the textview. I feel @brian's answer is probably correct if you're already getting the data within the bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm calling getView().findViewByID(R.id.theTextViewIWant), but it is always returning null, and the IDE says it cannot resolve getView()

I recommend to you to read [`getView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) method documentation, but there's a small explanation

> Get a View that displays the data at the specified position in the data set.

So if you want to find a view that's not on a data set, for instance in your example `TextView` then you want to use [`findViewById(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int))

> Finds a view that was identified by the android:id XML attribute that was processed in onCreate(Bundle).

As it says in the documentation I recommend you to put it on `onCreate()` method, instead of `onStart()`.

Then you have to remove the `getView()` and do it like :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.yourLayoutFromActivity2);
  TextView textViewBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
}
```

Note : if you put your stuff in `onStart()` it means that every-time the app come from foreground will execute all of you have inside of it. I also recommend to you to take a look at [`Android life cycle`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6812066/4385913)

Comment: This answer did it for me - the key being your "setContentView(R.layout.yourLayoutFromActivity2)". My original code was returning null because I was trying to find a TextView that was defined in an .xml file different from the one that was set as the contentView (in my case, a fragment that wasn't launched yet). Thank you very much for your help, if anyone has a similar problem take care of looking at what view you're manipulating!

Comment: If it worked feel free to mark this answer as a correct :D

Answer (score 1):

The IDE is telling you `getView()` is not an `Activity` method (it is however a [`Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#getView()) method). In an `Activity` you can simply call [`findViewById()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)).

```
TextView textViewBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
```

Comment: This answer is correct, my issue was different (in hindsight I believe I didn't explain everything correctly on the question), but once I referenced a TextView within the activity .xml file this worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The getView() is a fragment method. You need to use findViewById() in the activity to initialize the view. Also move the initialization code to onCreate method and process the intent there as well.