# How to perform an action after Activity is started and displayed

Tags: android, android-activity, oncreate

I have two Activities. `A` and `B`. `A` starts `B`.

In `B.onCreate()`I call a function to download a file I need in that activity: `DownloadFile()`.

For that purpose, `B` has a progressbar I hide as soon as the download is finished.

What I expected was the following progression:

- `A` calls `startActivity()`
- `B` is shown

  - `B` shows the `progressbar`
  - `B` calls `onCreate`
  - `B.DownloadFile()` is called
  - `B` hides `progressBar`

But what actually happens is:

- `A` calls `startActivity()`

  - The screen is stuck on `A`
  - `B` calls `onCreate`
  - `B.DownloadFile()` is called
  - `B` never shows `progressBar`
- `B` is shown, file already downloaded, hiding progresbar immediatly.

Now, when I did the same thing in the same progression but instead of downloading the file, I streamed it, it all worked fine. But this could have something to do with how the `MediaPlayer` handles things.

I tried switching `onCreate` for `onStart` or `onResume` from what I've seen on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6812066/4687402). But the same thing happens.

I want to switch the activity and only *after* `B` is shown, I want the download to start, but I don't know how.

### Edit

As requested, the code for `B`

```
package com.skillcademy360.lite.activities

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity

class DownloadActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        DownloadFile()
    }

    fun DownloadFile() {
    }
}
```

As I said, I already tried to switch `onCreate` for `onStart` and `onResume` and even `onPostCreate`, which shouldn't be used anyway. But none of them work.

EDIT:

I realize there is some ways to work around this problem but I need a direct way. All of this is tied to a inheritance and a library, so doing things like "saving the file as a global variable" won't do.

The code I provided above behaves the same way mine does, so I need this problem exactly fixed without having a workaround using AsyncTasks or global variables.

EDIT:
To clarify. I get that, when I call it in `onCreate` the `DownloadFile()` blocks the UI. However, as shown below, same thing happens when I call it in `onResume`. As I understand it, and as its written in [the lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle), the **visible lifecycle** should start after `onStart`, but it doesn't seem to do that.

```
package com.skillcademy360.lite.activities

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity

class DownloadActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onResume(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onResume(savedInstanceState)
        DownloadFile()
    }

    fun DownloadFile() {
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide B activity's on create code

Comment: Please share your code i think , you call DownloadFile in your oncreate(),Do you change DownloadFile() location from onCreate() to onStart()?

Comment: show us some code, we can't guess.

Comment: Or do you change DownloadFile() method location from onCreate() to onResume()?

Comment: Ive added the code but its very simple so I don't know if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle):

`onStart()` called when the activity is becoming visible to the user.
Followed by `onResume()` if the activity comes to the foreground, or onStop() if it becomes hidden.

You can try to call your `DownloadFile()` method creating background `Thread` (so downloading couldn't block UI) in B Activity `onCreate()` and start to show your `ProgressBar` in `onResume()` or in `onStart()`.

**EDIT**: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3028660/10326629)

**EDIT 2**: If you don't want to work with global variable then you can call your `DownloadFile()` method in `onCreate()`, show `ProgressBar` and then do all your stuff `onPostDelayed()` including dissmissing of `ProgressBar`

**EDIT 3**: You probably cannot show animated `ProgressBar` while you are downloading file at the same `Thread` since your downloading will block entire UI.

**EDIT 4**:

- The real progression of your actions is next:

  • `A` calls `startActivity()`

  • `onCreate()` method is called in `B`

  • `ProgressBar` is setup in `onCreate()` but will be shown only in
  `onResume()`

  • Method `DownloadFile()` started and blocked entire UI

  • Methods `onStart()` and `onResume()` weren't called because of
  `DownloadFile()` exectuing. That is why you stucked on the screen of
  `Activity A`

  • `DownloadFile()` is finished, methods `onStart()` and
  `onResume()` were called. `ProgressBar` is dissmissed.

Comment: I use my downloaded file in the onPostCreate method so it can't really do it async. Or at least it would create a large overhead. As you suggested, at "onStart" it should already be visible so I'd like to do it that way.

Comment: Just create global variable of your file `object`. Download it in background `Thread` and initialize this vairable somewhere in `onSuccessDownload()`. Then use this `object` fluent after `onCreate()`

Comment: I also updated my answer, take a look at that post.

Comment: I still consider all of these `workarounds` but thats not how the activity is supposed to work, is it? I mean, I could have figured out how to do it with AsyncTask but I already have many of those and as you said yourself, `onStart` and `onResume` is supposed to be called *after* the activity is visible. I want to fix this *directly*. And I want to understand why this is happening.

Comment: What do you mean under `thats not how the activity supposoed to work`? Your expectetion of following progression after `startActivity()` were wrong. Activity behaves as it should. You cannot show `ProgressBar` in `onCreate`. You can setup it there, but it will be shown in `onResume`. Calling `DownloadFile` blocks your entire UI, that is why you are stucking at previous screen until Loading is finished.

Comment: No. Its not about the progress bar. Its about the whole activity. The App doesn't even show a "black screen" or anything, it shows the old activity `A`. Even if I do my download in `onResume`. The "visible lifetime" is supposed to be after `onStart`, so I would expect at least the activity to switch after `onStart` is called. So, when `onResume` is reached, isn't it supposed to already be visible?

Comment: But I've tried the same thing with `onResume` and that doesn't work either. Shouldn't it?

Comment: If you show your `ProgressBar` in `onResume()` and then call `DownloadFile()` your screen also will be freezed. The only difference is that you will have freezed screen of `Activity B` with stopped `ProgressBar` image on it.

Comment: But thats exactly my problem: This does not happen. Instead of seeing a frozen `ProgressBar`, I see activity `A`.

Comment: Can you provide your attempt to call it in `onResume()`?

Comment: Please forget the ProgressBar. Its not about the ProgressBar. Its about the Activity not being shown *at all* before the download has finished.

Comment: I'd advised you to add logs into all states of `Activity Lifecycle`. Starting from `onPause()` of `Activity A` to `onStop()` of `Activity B`. It helps you and me to understand the situation

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to create the progress bar in the activity A, so you are sure that it is called when your intent starts. 
Download file in B and then only cancel it.

Can you please show some code if it is still not working like this? 
Whats happens if you use debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using AsyncTask, show your progressBar in onPreExecute() method, download your file in doInBackground() and hide the progress bar in onPostExecute(),

Than you can execute this AsyncTask from your Activity B's onCreate() method.

Hope this helps.

Ankit Dubey