# Status bar re-appearance upon minimisation of fullscreen Android app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I am developing a very simple fullscreen Android app: when started It will present a picture; no buttons, no actions. I have a problem with the top status bar as shown in the images of emulator below:
1) When I start the app everything is fine and I would like it to stay that way.
2) Once I click the square button to minimise the app I have a view over all opened programs, this is fine too.
3) Once I click on my app again it is maximised but the green top bar is now visible on top. I wish it looked like in (1)...

[image]

Below I paste my FullscreenActivity.java:

```
package com.example.myapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 */
public class FullscreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * Some older devices needs a small delay between UI widget updates
     * and a change of the status and navigation bar.
     */
    private static final int UI_ANIMATION_DELAY = 0; //300;
    private final Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    private View mContentView;
    private final Runnable mHidePart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Delayed removal of status and navigation bar

            // Note that some of these constants are new as of API 16 (Jelly Bean)
            // and API 19 (KitKat). It is safe to use them, as they are inlined
            // at compile-time and do nothing on earlier devices.
            mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        }
    };
    private View mControlsView;
    private final Runnable mShowPart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Delayed display of UI elements
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            if (actionBar != null) {
                actionBar.show();
            }
            mControlsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };
    private final Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            hide();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bluescreen);
        mControlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
        mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        hide();
    }

    private void hide() {
        // Hide UI first
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.hide();
        }
        mControlsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Schedule a runnable to remove the status and navigation bar after a delay
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mShowPart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHidePart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your activity goes to the background and then you bring it to front, the flags that you set are reseted. You call `hide()` from `onPostCreate()` which is called only when the activity is created or the screen is rotated.

If you want the `hide()` method to be called also when your app gets back from the background call it from `onStart()` or `onWindowFocusChanged()` when focus is true.

Comment: Thanks! I called the hide() from onStart() and it works.
In case someone will face a similar problem, here is a nice flowchart of actions
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812003/difference-between-oncreate-and-onstart