# How to run a function, when an Activity gets visible? ( onResume does not work properly)

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I would like to start a foreground service, as soon as the Acitvity gets visible. I tried this, by overriding the `onResume`, but when I compile and run my app, it gets called even if the screen is turned off.

If the screen is turned off, I get `IllegalStateException` if I try to start a foreground service.

I wrapped the code inside a try-catch block. It mostly works, but sometimes it is not called after the screen gets visible, just right before that.

How is it possible to run a code every time when my Activity is visible by the user?

Comment: `onResume()` is your best shot. Check whether there are any other triggers which starts the service. Try putting a debug point or a log to `onResume()` and check whether it really gets called when the app is in background. I highly doubt it.

Comment: Can you give more context? Why do you get `IllegalStateException` in `Service`? What is the root cause of it? Never met such an exception in services.

Comment: Or share the code and I will try to reproduce it

Comment: Can you share the exception stack trace. It is helpful to find root cause. I don't think it's a problem of `onResume()`

Comment: you async method inside onStart then start your foreground service there

Comment: There is NO such "single" method in Android framework, you will have to use several callbacks to be 100% sure. But that is everyday reality of Android programming, right?

Answer (score 1):

Well `onResume` is not you method. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6812066/9248201) is a pretty neet explanation of basic differences between `onCreate` and `onStart`

As you've already understood the method you need is `onStart` because it gets called directly after the activity becomes visible to a user.

Comment: `onStart` does not guarantee that the activity is **visible**. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

For Foreground Services it's not important from which callback of Activity you start them, because they can work even if app is working background.

You can get `IllegalStateException` if you start Foreground Service without calling `startForeground` method. Make sure the code of your Service contains code similar to the following:

```kotlin
class ExampleService : Service() {

   override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        // prepare pending intent
        val pendingIntent = val pendingIntent: PendingIntent =
        Intent(this, ExampleActivity::class.java).let { notificationIntent ->
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0)
        }

        // build notification to display while foreground service is running
        val notification = 
            NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "channel_id")
               .setContentTitle("Title")
               .setContentText("Text")
               .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
               .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_icon)
               .build()

        val notificationId = 42

        // call tell the system run your service as foreground service
        startForeground(notificationId, notification)
     
        // implement the business logic  
        ....
    }
   
}
```

You can find more info about Foreground Services here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services

Answer (score 0):

Well actually also `onStart` can be called before the content is **visible**.
I had the same issue when I wanted to start an animation only after it is really visible..

If you want to be 100% sure that the view is visible before running your code, you can do the following:

```
        requireActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // your code
            }
        });
```

This will create a runnable that is queued up and runs after all other UI components are loaded. You can call this in `onViewCreated()`, `onResume()` or `onStart()` it doesn't matter.