# How to know if an activity is called using startActivityForResult or simply called by using startActivity?

Tags: android

or should i send some extra data in the Intent to know the call ?if there is no predefined method,like `getIntent` and do something with it ?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

***I know this question is answered already but I have a better solution..***

When your activity was started just by `startActivity()` a `getCallingActivity()` method in target activity will return `null`. When it was called by `startActivityForResult()` it will return name of calling activity.

See [getCallingActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingActivity%28%29) for more details.

So you can check in Activity before finishing for calling activity. If result is null Activity was called by  `startActivity()` and if result is not null then Activity was called by `startActivityForResult()`. Thats it.

example :-

```
if (getCallingActivity() == null) {
    //This Activity was called by startActivity 
} else {
   //This Activity was called by startActivityForResult
}
```

Comment: Please note that `getCallingActivity()` returns `null` if the activity launch mode of the started activity is `singleTask` or `singleInstance`, or started with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce In such cases, I think there is no meaning of using `startActivityForResult` to call such Activity which uses these flags. So the result is as expected. What you say?

Comment: I don't know, all I know is that I ran into a `NullPointerException` today, and the fix was to remove `singleInstance` from the launch mode.

Answer (score 6):

I think that you should expose several intents for the same activity in your manifest, then test the calling intent to adapt your behaviour.

Example for your activity intent filter in the manifest:

```
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
```

and corresponding code in your activity onCreate:

```
if (getIntent().getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)) {
        // do whatever you need to do here
} else if (getIntent().getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PICK)){
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can put a flag like "0" and "1" , putting it in intent, so if "0" then its startActivity or "1" for startActivityForResult... this is simple, isnt it?

Comment: This is kind of messy because you handle more data than you really need. The answer below from @PankajKumar is the cleanest possible one.