# android: how to know whether app was called by another app

Tags: android, android-layout

I managed to register my app as camera app via

```
<activity android:name=".CameraActivity" android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Now, I would like to know whether my app was startet as intent or directly by the user, so I can react accordingly:

- returning an image via setResult (in case of returning to the previous app)
- saving the image to disk (in those cases where no previous app is involved)

Anyone knows how to get this information?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564461/how-to-know-if-an-activity-is-called-using-startactivityforresult-or-simply-call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analyse the value of intent.getAction() to determine whether the activity was launched by the home/launcher, or by another application using the "IMAGE_CAPTURE" action.

Answer (score 2):

[`Activity.getIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent%28%29) will return the `Intent` that initiated your activity, so you can examine the intent's action/category/etc. to determine what your activity should do.