# startActivityForResult is not returning, but it seems like I'm doing everything right

Tags: android, onactivityresult

My startActivityForResult is not returning to onActivityResult when the logout Preference is selected. The strange thing is that I'm pretty sure it used to work before I starting converting to using REST calls, but I don't know what might have been changed. MainOverview activity calls the Settings Activity. Yes, the onCreate method is omitted for MainOverview since I don't think it's important here. Here's the MainOverview code:

```
public class MainOverviewActivity extends BaseActivity implements OnClickListener
{
  public void onClick(View v)
  {
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.show_settings:
      openSettings();
      break;
    }
  }

  public static final String INTENT_RESULT_LOGOUT = "logout";

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
  {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.i("MainOverviewActivity", "onActivityResult before finish() :)");

    if(requestCode == 123)
    {
      if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
      {
        if(data.getBooleanExtra(SettingsActivity.INTENT_RESULT_LOGOUT, false))
        {
           Log.i("MainOverviewActivity", "finish() :)");

           Intent i = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
           startActivity(i);

           finish();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  protected void openSettings()
  {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 123);
  }
}
```

Here's my Settings activity code:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity 
{

  public static final String INTENT_RESULT_LOGOUT = "logout";

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra(INTENT_RESULT_LOGOUT, true);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    finish();
  }
```

Here's my settings.xml page, where I'm getting a "java.lang.NullPointerException at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeXmlBlockParser.next(BridgeXmlBlockParser.java:301)" on the preview page, and I have no idea why:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Server account">
        <Preference
            android:title="Logout"
            android:key="logout" />
        <Preference
            android:title="Version"
            android:key="version" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
  </PreferenceScreen>
```

It makes it to the onResume() within MainOverview, but not onActivityResult(), and I'm boggled as to why. Resultcode is above 0. 
Any suggestions would be great. I've read several other StackOverflow pages, and haven't seen an answer yet. I am not setting the launchMode anywhere. I'm out of ideas.

I've been working on it for a week and am still stuck.

Thanks in advance!

Devin

Comment: I looked [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564461/how-to-know-if-an-activity-is-called-using-startactivityforresult-or-simply-call) and noticed that getCallingActivity() does return null when the the preference is clicked. Somehow it's not retaining the fact that it was created by startActivityOnResult. Why is that?

Comment: Despite what the docs say, onResume is getting called when the activity returns, and onActivityResult is not getting called. I'm becoming more confused the more I investigate. Some more help/suggestions would be great!

Comment: What are you doing when the `Preference`s are clicked in `SettingsActivity`? Also, are you doing anything fancy in your `AndroidManifest`, like `android:noHistory` or `android:launchMode`?

Comment: noHistory or launchMode never gets set anywhere in my project. I'm currently not allowing any preferences to be clicked in SettingsActivity so as to simplify it and eliminate any bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help, I finally discovered that the code was returning to onResume() in another class, which is where the LoginActivity was being created. It still doesn't ever return to onActivityResult, which doesn't make sense to me, but it at least works again.

Thanks again for all your help! I learned a good bit from your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
setResult(123, returnIntent);
```

with

```
setresult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
```

The result code is the first parameter - the 123 is known only to the calling activity

Comment: Thanks for responding! I sure was hopeful, but I'm afraid that didn't fix it, though I still edited my code accordingly. My previous code did leave out a constant with value 123 that I was using in the parent activity. It just never makes it back to onActivityResult.

Comment: Instead it returns back to MainOverviewActivity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need to check the parent when you logout. Use the below insted.

```
public void logout() 
{

Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra(INTENT_RESULT_LOGOUT, true);

setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);

finish();
}
```

Comment: The previous programmer put the parent check there, with no explanation as to why. Either way, every time I've stepped through it, it runs just the setResult call, not the getParent().

Comment: See my comment on my original post above for more insight.

Comment: @DevinCrane I think this is the issue, since the setResult() tells the activity that a startActivityForResult() was called. It should then go to the onActivityResult() automatically.

Comment: @epsilonDelta Thank you for your answer, but I don't understand. I'm calling setResult().

Comment: @DevinCrane Correct but by creating a new Intent by giving it parameters of classes, you are implying that you wish to start a new "chain" of switching between classes (it shows that you didn't do a startActivityForResult()). Also, make the change that Greg said below.

Comment: I think Greg's answer will do it.

Comment: @epsilondelta Thanks! I understand now. The other StackOverflow I saw that on must have been wrong. I edited my code above accordingly, but it still doesn't fix it. The code gets into SettingsActivity just fine and runs each line, but it refuses to return to onActivityResult. I keep thinking I've got everything right.