# Do Activity changes, based on the calling activity

Tags: android, view, android-activity

I am using start activity for result which opens another activity and returns the intent which contains extras.

Anyway, I would like to know if the following is possible.
I will give an example to make it easier to understand what i am trying do.

Lets say  we have 
activity A 
activity B
and activity C which is the activity A and B start for a result.

I would like to know if I can state, if from activity A launched  C, C reveals a hidden spinner. If it was B that launched C, the spinner remains hidden.

Basically activity C changes based on which activity started it.

Is there a way of achieving this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to know the calling activity in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967799/how-to-know-the-calling-activity-in-android)

Comment: In the particularity of a `startActivityForResult`, the second answer to the duplicate question is more relevant: use `getCallingActivity()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***You can use [getCallingActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingActivity%28%29) method to do your task. 
Read class name from that and match with name of your `ActivityA` and `ActivityB`.***

---

*Write below code into Activity C.*

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ....

    // Below is code to setup
    String callingActivity = getCallingActivity().getShortClassName().replace(".", "");
    if (ActivityA.class.getSimpleName().equals(callingActivity)) {
        // Activity has been called by Activity A
    } else if (ActivityB.class.getSimpleName().equals(callingActivity)) {
     // Activity has been called by Activity B
    }
}
```

---

Other resorces are [how to know the calling activity in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967799/how-to-know-the-calling-activity-in-android) and  [How to know if an activity is called using startActivityForResult or simply called by using startActivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564461/how-to-know-if-an-activity-is-called-using-startactivityforresult-or-simply-call/17060830#17060830)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)

You pass in a resultCode int. Why don't you check that value in Activity C and set up your spinner based on that? Alternatively, you can just pass a Bundle with some value that you check.

Comment: this is not relevant to the question. The requestcode does not reach the started activity

Answer (score 0):

Activity A: do this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(this, Other_Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("HIDE_SPINNER", false);
startActivity(intent);
```

Activity B: do this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(this, Other_Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("HIDE_SPINNER", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

Activity C: do this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  if (extras != null) {
   Boolean shouldHide = extras.getBoolean("HIDE_SPINNER");
   if (shouldHide ) {
        // hide it
   } else {
        // show it
   }
}
```