# Android get previous activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 2 activities: `Activity1` and `Activity2`.
In each of this activities there is a button that leads me to a third activity (`MainActivity`). In `MainActivity` I want to know from which activity page was called.

Comment: +1 - agree with @variant-45, put an `int` or anything else as flag from the caller `Activity`

Comment: Add activity flag to identify than put intent to mainActivity and please dear put code in ques.. so any one can idea fro reply

Comment: Possibly a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967799/how-to-know-the-calling-activity-in-android

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use the putExtra attribute of the Intent to pass the name of the Activity.

Calling Activity,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Next.class);
intent.putExtra("activity","first");
startActivity(intent);
```

Next Activity,

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String activity = intent.getStringExtra("activity");
```

Now in the string activity you will get the name from which Activity it has came.

Comment: If the calling activity is not from the same app ?

Comment: But if you refactor the name of the activity you may miss that. I would prefer something built in. Calling a method from android's API. Something like "getCallingActivity()".

Answer (score 23):

You can use:

```
public ComponentName getCallingActivity()
```

to know which Activity called your current `Activity`.

Comment: Only works if you start the activty with `startActivityForResult()`, not `startActivity()`.

Answer (score 6):

Use putExtra() to identify the previous activity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, MainActivity.class).putExtra("from", "activity1");
startActivity(i);
```

To check the activity in Main Activity,

```
if(getIntent().getStringExtra("from").equals("activity1")){
//From Activity 1
}else {
// Activity 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you move from one activity to another you can Pass the activity Name as given below

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, deliveries.class);
i.putExtra("ActivityName", "ActivityOne");
startActivity(i);
```

and check the activity name in the other activity

```
Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
String activityName = Long.parseLong(extra.getSerializable("ActivityName")
toString());
```

I think it can solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

when you start your activity :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, HistoryDetailsResults.class);
 intent.putExtra(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE, activity.getLocalClassName());
 activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Using `Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE` I assume you use a good practice.
(`Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE` is the `String` : *'activity'*)

`activity.getLocalClassName()` give this : *view.YourActivity* as `String`

EDIT : Instead of using activity `activity.getLocalClassName()` I prefer use `activity.getClass().getSimpleName()`

### Step 1 in your start activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, HistoryDetailsResults.class);
 intent.putExtra(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE, activity.getClass().getSimpleName());
 activity.startActivity(intent);
```

### Step 2 in your destination activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String startActivity = intent.getStringExtra(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)
String activityToCompare = YourActivityToCompare.class.getSimpleName()
```

And what you want to do :

```
if( startActivity.equalsIgnoreCase(activityToCompare) {
    //Do what you want
}
```