# Determining the previous activity class

Tags: android

When entering a preference activity or an option screen, I want to be able to know what was the previous activity. Is there some built in method or class to know which activity was before the current activity/ preference activity you are in?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the putExtra attribute of the Intent to pass the name of the Activity.

Calling Activity,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, next.class);
intent.putExtra("activity","first");
startActivity(intent);
```

Next Activity,

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String activity = intent.getStringExtra("activity");
```

Now in the string activity you will get the name from which Activity it has came.

Comment: From: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119526/android-get-previous-activity

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. So I guess there is no method/class.

Comment: No built in method sadly.

Comment: What about the back stack?

Answer (score 0):

You could do that without a Bundle...

Activity A starts Activity B over this Method of Activity B.

```
public class B extends Activity{

     private static String previousActivity;

     public static start(Context ctx, String prevAct){
         previousActivity = prevAct;
         Intent i = new Intent(ctx,currentActivity.class);
         ctx.startActivity(i);
     }
...
```