# find previous page using onBackPressed

Tags: android, android-activity

when i click the back button on an android device, the onBackPressed will fire and it will navigate me to the previous activity.

is there a way how i can know which is the previous activity?

thanks in advance

clive

Comment: This should help you http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getParent%28%29

Comment: Are you wanting to know if the previous activity is yours? You can do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119526/android-get-previous-activity).

Comment: @AntonioCalì if i get the parent of the activity, it wont help me

Comment: @thegrinner the activities in the application are all mine. in other words i am not going to be able to access my application through another application. 

If i have 2 activities, activity AA and activity BB. if from AA i go to BB and from BB i go to AA again. if i touch the back button, from AA i go to BB. now i need to confirm that if i touch the back button again, i go from BB to AA.  i believe that intents will be lost since you are creating new ones all the time.

hope i explained myself better now

Comment: @CliveCauchi Have you tried what you described above and what happens? The intents should not be "lost" unless you add some special flags when starting the activities.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only want to know the name of the previous `Activity`, you can put the name of the previous `Activity` in the Intent using `putExtra(String name, String value)` method. Then you can get the name of the Activity in `onCreate` of the child Activity by using `getStringExtra(String name)` method on the Activity's Intent. You can get the intent by using the `getIntent()` method of the Activity.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`getCallingActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingActivity%28%29) if you started the activity to get results.

> Note: if the calling activity is not expecting a result (that is it
>   did not use the startActivityForResult(Intent, int) form that includes
>   a request code), then the calling package will be null.

So maybe you can *hack* it by starting the activities for result without actually providing a result.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe You can try this,

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

Comment: I need to know the name of the previous activity