# How to get the previous Activty?

Tags: java, android

We are in activity A and we do this following code :

```
if (previousActivity){  // what method calling the previous activity ?
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                LoginActivity.this,
                                CmdEndActivity.class);   // I want to go in CmdEndActivity
                        intent.putExtra("username", user);
                        intent.putExtra("useremail", email);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();

                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_left_in, R.anim.push_left_out);

                    }
                    else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                LoginActivity.this,
                                Reservation4.class);  // I want to go in Reservation4
                        intent.putExtra("username", user);
                        intent.putExtra("useremail", email);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();

                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_left_in, R.anim.push_left_out);

                    }
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Did you try to have and share previous activity information  between activities via SharedPreferences or Bundle & PutExtras?

Comment: Your question is **un - clear**

Comment: What is `previousActivity`? Is it any string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android get previous activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119526/android-get-previous-activity)

Comment: Please put some code with the question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now I add the code

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `putExtra` in `Intent` to pass the activity name to another one. and then at destination activity use `getIntent` and check if this is equal to `Activity 1` or `Activity 2`. Something like below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("activity_name", "Activity 1");
startActivity(intent);
```

And in Activity 2 check the extra value:

```
String activity_name = getIntent().getStringExtra("activity_name");
if(activity_name.equal("Activity 1")){
  //... goto Activity B
}else if(activity_name.equal("Activity 2")){
  // ... goto Activity C
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Abdou it's just a sample code and I typed it here. add your code to your question for better help.