# How can i get Parent class Activity Name in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have three Activity classes,

1.MainActivity

2.firstActivity

3.SecondActivity

In Activity classes interactions are  MainActivity->FirstActivity->SecondActivity

I want to retrive the name of the calling activity for knowing activity names and activity flows and for other works.

Comment: How does you start your activity? By using startActivityForResult?

Comment: I'm not using that,i'm using like  startActivity(intent);

Comment: You really shouldn't.  Providing different behavior in a function based on where you were called from is considered VERY bad design.  You should either use different functions or pass down the behavior you want in the arguments (although even that can become an antipattern quickly).

Comment: You can send the Activity name through `intent.putString("key","Here activity name")` and retrive the activity name through by its key `intent.getString("key")`;

Comment: Look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967799/how-to-know-the-calling-activity-in-android This might duplicate

Comment: @PankajKumar i have not seen that you are posted link,this question is just my thought.

Comment: @User Duplicate means similar question with answer. So I am not saying that you are doing somthing dulicate of others :)

Answer (score 0):

While starting `Activity` use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CallicingActivity.this , CalledActivity.class);
intent.putString("callingActivityname","CallicingActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

and get the Activityname

```
    Bundle extras =  getIntent().getExtras();
    String _callingallingActivityName = extras.getString("callingActivityname");
```

Answer (score 0):

After many trails i have done this.

**Get the Activity Name**

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 String activity = intent.getStringExtra("activity");
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), activity,  Toast  .LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**Calling Next Activity**

```
 Intent intentNew = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
 intentNew.putExtra("activity", "Activity2");
 startActivity(intentNew);
```