# Get the activity which started the current activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm looking for a way to get the activity (A) which started my current activity (B).

So A calls:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

I'm looking for some method I can call in B to get A, so something like (in B):

```
Activity a = someMethodToGetCallingActivity();
```

Any ideas?

CLOSING EDIT:

As all the comments below say, I'm trying to use Android incorrectly. I was looking to get the instance of the activity A, but since there's no guarantee it exists, I can't. It's not a duplicate of the other question suggested because they were trying to work out which Activity (out of many) fired off the current Activity, not trying to get the instance of a particular Activity. Thanks all :)

Comment: It's better to use Fragment within Activity A in this case, otherwise the communication channel will be extremely unreliable since the activity A will be paused and it can possibly be destroyed by the system

Comment: Agreed. Activity A does not have to exist. And, even if it does, you have no way, short of #EpicFail memory leaks, to get access to an instance of it. Solve your problem in some other way (e.g., event bus).

Comment: You want to get the name of the calling activity or the activity itself (I mean the activity object)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to know the calling activity in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967799/how-to-know-the-calling-activity-in-android)

Comment: I guess he wants the Activity object... but, what for?

Comment: @Mauker, it was to attach a listener to that Activity, so that when my background process did a certain thing, it would alert the Activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what about passing the activity A name in the intent data and storing it in Activity B when it start?

Comment: Except that I'm trying to get the instance of the Activity, not just the Activity class.

Comment: Then you're thinking wrong. Android doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get intent you came from.
You can pass intent nam as param or try to invoke some special method

Comment: What about `getIntent()` method of activity class ? It do return the intent that start the current activity. However it will not help getting the instance of the activity who fired the intent.

Comment: maybe I'm missing something. You want to get the name of the Activity or the object or what ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use intent.putExtras... 
And at next activity(B) just get that intent by getIntent and use get...Extra to get that data?

Answer (score 0):

You can not get intent of Activity A (previous Activity) yet you can pass the details of intent via bundle to Activity B.