# how to edit activity hierarchy android android java

Tags: java, android, android-activity, hierarchy

Is there a way to edit the activity hierarchy(if that's what it is called)? For example...

I have an app with three activities. This is the path to transition between activities.

```
Activity1 --> Activity2 --> Activity3
```

If you press the back button, it looks like this...

```
Activity3 --> Activity2 --> Activity1
```

My problem is if the app is terminated and it receives a notification, the user can go straight to Activity3. If they then press the back button, it closes the app and they can't get back to Activity1. I don't want to use intents to get to a page when the back button is pressed. Is there a way to edit the activity hierarchy? If not, what would my best option be to solve this?

Comment: check this it might be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4968327/6244429

Comment: I don't see how that post helps my problem.